# AJAX and/or JQUERY form POST?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Hi Masters Of Web Programming,
here I come with another stupid question, hoping someone will answer me. I'm not very good in AJAX programming but due some situations I must build a completely non-refreshable site.
Next question is how to make this form to send a request and return the result, WITHOUT reload of current page?

```
    <?PHP

function mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, $debug=0) {

    $res_lines = file("http://www.mobio.bg/code/checkcode.php?servID=$servID&code=$code");

    $ret = 0;
    if($res_lines) {

        if(strstr("PAYBG=OK", $res_lines[0])) {
            $ret = 1;
        }else{
            if($debug)
                echo $line."\n";
        }
    }else{
        if($debug)
            echo "Unable to connect to mobio.bg server.\n";
        $ret = 0;
    }

    return $ret;
}


$servID = 29;
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
$ok = $_REQUEST["ok"];

if($ok) {
    if(mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, 0) == 1) {
        echo "The SMS code is correct!";
    }else{
        echo "Wrong SMS code.";
    }
}else{
?>



<form method="post" name="smscode">
SMS code: <input type="text" size="20" name="code"/>
<input type="submit" name="ok" value=" Submit "/>
</form>
<?PHP } ?>
```

This form sends request to verify SMS code. It is what providers of this service gave to me.  But it's simple php file. I included it to my non-refreshable site but when I press SUBMIT button it refreshes whole current page and then shows the predefined echo.

Comment: are you already using jQuery elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, my whole site is in Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All solutions are not working in my case. Either they don't POST to server or I can't make them show the reply from server, which as you might see is inside the same file

```
if($ok) {
    if(mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, 0) == 1) {
        echo "The SMS code is correct!";
    }else{
        echo "Wrong SMS code.";
    }
```

So in this situation can anyone tell me how to reload only the div that contains this file included in it, on SUBMIT button click?
Or any other solution will be welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submit use simple button and bind ajax event to it. Here's the rough example.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btnId").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "test.js",
           dataType: "script"
         });

       });
     });
```

Comment: It can be any url that will accept ajax request and trigger response back.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a lot when i started doing some ajaxing:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

it will get you the behavior you are describing.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        // other options left out
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    }; 
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 


// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  { 
    alert('response: ' + responseText); 
}
```

Comment: This plugin is ok, he posts what I need but how to make him return the result from my form?

Comment: Check out the Code Samples tab. There is an option to pass a callback to do what you want with the response.  I edited my answer to show an example that i took right from the code sample.